# Suggested reference for mean squared residuals over a sub-region, and definition

Tags: regression, variance, modeling, residuals

I am doing some modeling for spectral line-shape fits. The objective function is the mean squared residuals for the model function versus the experimental values.

I need to describe the mean squared residual over a sub-region for the analysis. Namely, Emin < E < Emax excluding some outliers. Is there a definition for such regional mean square residual?
And are there any references for any future publication?

Comment: There are several plausible definitions.  They all require some kind of measure on the sub-region: either a probability distribution or (as is likely) an assumed uniform distribution.  It *sounds* like you just need to compute the expectation of the squared residuals (truncated to the given subregion).  Perhaps you could tell us what this mean squared residual is intended to represent?

Comment: mean squared residual = mean squared error to be used as the objective or cost function for the nonlinear model fit of a model equation for the spectra. The analysis addresses some sub-region or domain where the mean squared residual is of better quality for the fit for different models/equations. I am interested in an already used definition.

Comment: The issue is that "better quality" should depend on the application.  For instance, for quantitation you want to recover the area under the peaks accurately; but for identification or calibration, you want to locate the peaks correctly: those lead to two (very) different cost functions.